# NoClassDefFoundError when starting apache solr

Tags: apache, solr

When I try start apache solr:

> java -jar start.jar

I get NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/common/SolrException

How can I resolve that?

EDIT:
I downloaded apache-solr-1.4.1 and extracted. On command line I go to example catalog and type java -jar start.jar

Comment: where did you get the start.jar? did you download the solr1.4.1.zip and extracted that?

Comment: maybe your JDK / JRE is screwed up? can you try reinstalling it? also, what's the full exception stack trace?

Comment: Whats the output of `java -version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been very long time since you asked the question. Now 3.4.0 is out. Does the problem still exist? Your java version seems correct but you are not using GNU's GCJ, right? Because in the tutorial part, It says that it does not work with that version.

Answer (score 1):

This means, that you're not using the right Java Version. Update it to the latest Version and try it again. Should solve the problem.

Comment: I updated java to newest version and uninstalled old versions. The problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

Please **download the latest version of solr** from the Apache Solr website. You **should have java 8 or higher and your JAVA_HOME must be set** too accordingly to have the solr up and running.